# cargo would not build even when src/main.rs is available

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I am trying to build using cargo build. The following is the project structure

```
tree
.
├── Cargo.toml
└── src
    └── main.rs
```

The content of Cargo.toml

```
[package]
name = "server"
version = "0.1.0"
authors = ["Lokanath Mohanty <lokanath.mohanty@adcolony.com>"]
edition = "2018"

# See more keys and their definitions at https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html

[dependencies]
```

The content of src/main.rs

```
use std::io::{ErrorKind, Read, Write};
use std::net::TcpListener;
use std::sync::mpsc;
use std::thread;
use std::time::Duration;

const LOCAL_IP: &str = "127.0.0.1:6001";
const MSG_SIZE: usize = 32;


fn main() {
    ...
}
```

I am getting the following error -

```
error: failed to parse manifest at `/home/debashishc/Downloads/Cargo.toml`

Caused by:
  no targets specified in the manifest
  either src/lib.rs, src/main.rs, a [lib] section, or [[bin]] section must be present
```

Comment: [Are you sure ?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zd3leJcGYqY) hint "`/home/debashishc/Downloads/Cargo.toml`"

Comment: I don't know what you mean. The code I have uploaded are correct.

Comment: - - what give the command `ls /home/debashishc/Downloads/src/main.rs` ?

Comment: That file does not exist. But I am running the command from the directory '/home/debashishc/Downloads/Rust/server'. This directory does have a Cargo.toml. Why is it looking for a Cargo.toml in /home/debashishc/Downloads ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cargo looks for and tries to [parse `Cargo.toml` in parent directories](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html#the-workspace-field), because it checks whether your crate is part of a larger [workspace](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch14-03-cargo-workspaces.html).

Remove the broken `Cargo.toml` from the parent directory. Alternatively, make your crate's `Cargo.toml` a workspace to stop cargo from searching further.